# Get json from Web Service

Tags: java, jquery, json, web-services, rest

I have a `REST` Web Service on Spring and now i want to **split it into Server and Client**.
**When everything was as one application it worked fine**, but now i'm facing some issues.

I don't  receive data from server, though i get `200 OK` from it.

Server-side (`http://localhost:8085`)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class RestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userLogin}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Wrapper edit(@PathVariable String userLogin) {
        return wrapper.wrap(userService.findByLogin(userLogin));
    }
}
```

Client-side (`http://localhost:8089`)

```
function editUser(login) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8085/user/" + login,
        async: false,
        success: function (resp) {
            alert("asdasdasdasdasdas");            
        }
    });
}
```

When i manually access link `http://localhost:8085/user/user1` i see such line in browser

```
{"id":1,"login":"user1","password":"user1","passValid":"user1","email":"user1@user1.nix","firstname":"user1","lastname":"user1","birthday":"1940-08-10","roleid":"User"}
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add Producers as json

```
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
```

also add

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```

to get the specific error

Comment: No errors, but still doesn't work.  
Does it matter, that i start both server and client on one server TomCat? And when i launch client, i see in TomCat such line `WARNING: StandardServer.await: Invalid command '' received`. But it receives the request and selects user from DB.

Comment: When i use `jsonp` i don't see an answer from server, though it selects a user from DB.

Comment: use firebug and check the net section in that what is the response you are getting, also check what is the request header and response header for that ajax call

Comment: Sorry, i get the right response. It seems i've got another issue. Would you be so kind to check my another question in few minutes? I'll create it.

Answer (score 0):

try it in your js

```
         $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:URL+'/login',               
                dataType: "json",
                async:false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                }
         });
```